# Importing Turtle graphics modules

Tags: python, turtle-graphics

I admit I have just started with `turtle` graphics in Python 3.3, and following a youtube presentation started with `from turtle import *`. This allows such short commands as fd(100) in place of the format I see more often `turtle.forward(100)` etc.

My questions are:

1. In using this format am I using an unacceptable shortcut?
2. How can I stop Python IDLE from interpreting every command in this format as "Turtle graphics"?
3. Does the " * " suffix mean as it usually does, "everything"?

I apologize in advance if I should not be asking multiple questions in one post, but they are relevant to each other and this seemed logical.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, 'Michael10x2a' and 'dryatu', at 77 years of age, the learning curve seems rather steep at times.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Generally, yes, you do want to avoid using the form `from module import *`. That that does is that it opens up the module (a normal python file), and essentially takes every function, class, etc. defined within that file and adds it to your namespace. And you're right -- `*` does mean "everything".

So, if I wrote a module named `foo.py` that contained a function named `bar1`, `bar2`, etc, doing `from foo import *` would allow me to use these functions as if I had defined it within my current file:

```
from foo import *

bar1()
bar2()
# etc
```

The main reason why this is bad is that it takes an unknown amount of functions and classes and dumps it into your namespace. It makes it hard to track what's going on in larger codebases when you suddenly start using a function out of the blue. For example:

```
from a import *
from b import *
from c import *
# etc

example()
# Where did this come from? From module a, b, or c? What if both a and b define a 
# function named 'example'?
```

You're already aware of the `import module; module.function` form, but there's a third form which is also useful:

```
from turtle import fd, right, left  # etc

right(90)
fd(100)
backwards(300) # throws an error!
forwards(300)  # throws an error!
```

Now, I can cherry-pick the functions I want, know where they come from, and avoid polluting my namespace.

However, in your case, I wouldn't worry too much about it. Since you're experimenting and learning how to use the turtle module, I think it's more important to focus on that aspect rather then writing perfectly idiomatic Python.

Comment: One advance that the last format also has is that you can easily find where each function comes from.

Answer (score 0):

By using `from package import *` you're just importing everything optionally defined in an `__init__.py` file's `__all__` variable defined by the package you are importing from. `__all__` variable may be omitted and that's why you should **[read the details](https://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/modules.html#importing-from-a-package)**

Most of the time I'd use "import package" just to avoid polluting the namespace.